# Create the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse message instead of mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, servlet-filters

I am writing a unit test for filter to log request and response message. Can we create the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse message instead of mock to send as a input to doFilter() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just implement the interface. However, these are large interfaces, so it's a lot of code to maintain instead of the mock.

If your reason to not use a mock is a simple aversion to mocks (good!) note that there's really no difference between manually implementing a "mock" object and letting a framework do it for you; in both cases you're giving your code something different from what the web framework you end up using will use.

The code you're writing is perhaps better tested with integration tests - starting a real web server as part of your test harness and generating real HTTP requests.

If you *are* trying to solve an issue the mocks are creating for you by manually implementing the interface, here's an example of a custom HttpServletRequest implemented as an extension of the implementation that ships with Jetty:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.2/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/web/InternalJettyServletRequest.java